# Write a query to display the student id and address for the student "David". Note : The student name can be in any case

Tags: oracle

[image]

data in student table:

```
STUDENT_NAME STUDENT_ID   ADDRESS
------------ -----------  --------
  Anandhi          1        4th street
  Anitha           4        Cross cut
  david            7        Main Cross Street
  Kokila           8        Rao Street
  Mithali          9        OMR road
```

I have tried the query:

```
select student_id,address from student where student_name='david';
```

Expected Output:

```
STDENT_ID  ADDRESS
---------- ----------
         7 Main Cross Street
```

I have tried the following code, it executes successfully and gives the desired result, however it fails to clear one test case and IDK why?

Comment: What does "it fails to clear one test case" mean?

Comment: Please fix your link text and try to explain where the problem is

Comment: From your title "Note : The student name can be in any case". You do not appear to be comparing values and ignoring case.

Answer (score 1):

You may try lowercasing the student name column, then compare it to `david` in all lowercase.

```sql
SELECT ADDRESS
FROM student
WHERE LOWER(STUDENT_NAME) = 'david';
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure all student names are stored in LOWERCASE?
Second, is it all rows in your question present in the table or is it a subset?

If the answer is NO and it is a subset
then try

```
SELECT student_id,address FROM student WHERE LOWER(student_name) = 'david';
```

And if you are not sure about leading and trailing spaces
then try

```
SELECT student_id,address FROM student WHERE TRIM(LOWER(student_name)) = 'david';
```

Answer (score 0):

Actual Oracle versions currently supported (12.1.0.2 is EOL already) have `collate` clause, so since Oracle 12.2 you can use `collate` clause on different levels: Column level, table level, schema level, database level, session level, query level:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/column-level-collation-and-case-insensitive-database-12cr2

For example, for your case:

```sql
SELECT student_id,address FROM student WHERE student_name collate BINARY_AI = 'david';
```

Full test case with test data and results:

```sql
--test data:
with STUDENT(STUDENT_NAME,STUDENT_ID,ADDRESS) as 
(
select 'Anandhi' , 1, '4th street'        from dual union all
select 'Anitha'  , 4, 'Cross cut'         from dual union all
select 'david'   , 7, 'Main Cross Street' from dual union all
select 'Kokila'  , 8, 'Rao Street'        from dual union all
select 'Mithali' , 9, 'OMR road'          from dual 
) -- end of test data
-- main query:
SELECT student_id,address FROM student WHERE student_name collate BINARY_AI = 'david';

-- Results:
STUDENT_ID ADDRESS
---------- -----------------
         7 Main Cross Street
```